# Site-to-Site VPN: Can't ping between two routers through cloud

Tags: routing, vpn, packet-tracer

I'm trying to simulate a Site-to-Site VPN.

This is what my network looks like:

[image]

The VPN tunnel stands for connecting `Technology center router` to `R1`, the running configurations for `Technology center router` are these:

```
Current configuration : 1713 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname TCR
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2901/K9 sn FTX1524158U
license boot module c2900 technology-package securityk9
!
!
!
crypto isakmp policy 10
 encr aes
 authentication pre-share
 group 2
!
crypto isakmp key cisco address 10.2.2.2
!
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set VPN-SET esp-3des esp-sha-hmac
!
crypto map VPN-MAP 10 ipsec-isakmp 
 description VPN connection to R1
 set peer 10.2.2.2
 set transform-set VPN-SET 
 match address 100
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 bandwidth 64000
 ip address 10.1.1.1 255.0.0.0
 clock rate 128000
 crypto map VPN-MAP
!
interface Serial0/0/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/1/0
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/1/1
 switchport mode access
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/1/2
 switchport mode access
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/1/3
 switchport mode access
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.3.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.4.0 0.0.0.255
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line 0/2/0 0/2/7
 login
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

and the running configurations for `R1`:

```
Current configuration : 1503 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R1
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2901/K9 sn FTX1524PZ05
license boot module c2900 technology-package securityk9
!
!
!
crypto isakmp policy 10
 encr aes
 authentication pre-share
 group 2
!
crypto isakmp key cisco address 10.1.1.1
!
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set VPN-SET esp-3des esp-sha-hmac
!
crypto map VPN-MAP 10 ipsec-isakmp 
 description VPN connection to TCR
 set peer 10.1.1.1
 set transform-set VPN-SET 
 match address 100
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 bandwidth 64000
 ip address 10.2.2.2 255.0.0.0
 clock rate 128000
 crypto map VPN-MAP
!
interface Serial0/0/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/1/0
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/1/1
 switchport mode access
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/1/2
 switchport mode access
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/1/3
 switchport mode access
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line 0/2/0 0/2/7
 login
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

Why `R1` and  `Technology center router` can't ping on each other ?

Comment: First, can R1 ping the TCR without the tunnel?  What is the output of "show crypto ipsec sa"?  Look in your log messages for problems.

Comment: now I found a solution that I sat-up the LANs to bing the TCR without tunnel as u said, then i made the VPN tunnel and it works, but after I made the VPN tunnel other LANs can't ping on TCR. any idea why is that ? and how to make a seprate tunnel for each LAN to TCR ?